# Foreach 2 statement and if inside it

Tags: php, foreach

> Hello sir im really newbie on php

i need to take an answer and check it if it same with the keyanswer or not using array and foreach. to see how many correct answer he have

but i cant use 2 statement in foreach. 
help me sir, thank you

```html
<?php

$x=0;
foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $answer & $_POST['key'] as $key) {
 if($answer = $key){
 $x+1;
 }
 
}
echo $x;
 ?>
```

```html
<form name="coba" method="post" action="cobaradio.php" />

<p><i>Rate each question from 6 to 1, six being strongly 
agree and one being strongly disagree.</i></p>

1. I think the module guide/student handbook provided enough information about the 
module content, organisation and assessment.<br/>

6<input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="6"> 5<input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="5"> 
4<input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="4"> 3<input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="3"> 
2<input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="2"> 0<input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="key[0]" value="2">
</p>
<p><i>Rate each question from 6 to 1, six being strongly 
agree and one being strongly disagree.</i></p>

1. I think the module guide/student handbook provided enough information about the 
module content, organisation and assessment.<br/>

1<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="1"> 4<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="4"> 
2<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="2"> 5<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="5"> 
3<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="3"> 6<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="6">
<input type="hidden" name="key[1]" value="3">
</p>
<button type="submit" name="waha">Tekan</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can we see your form?  Feel free to edit the question.

Comment: wait sir, i dont know how to edit this question

Comment: click the [edit] button

Comment: done sir i alr edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php

$x = 0;
$_POST['answer'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$_POST['key']    = array(1, 7, 6, 43, 5);

array_map(function ($n, $m) use (&$x) {
    if ($n == $m) {
        $x++;
    }
}, $_POST['answer'], $_POST['key']);

echo $x;//2
```

Comment: 2  (Is this what you want？)

Comment: yes sir, this is working well. thank you. you're really helping. can u explain to me about that method sir?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the indexes on the `$_POST['answer']` and `$_POST['key']` match:

```php
$rightAnswers = 0;

foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $index => $answer) {
    if ($answer = $_POST['key'][$index]) {
        $rightAnswers++;
    }
}

echo $rightAnswers . ' right answers';
```

Comment: what is => mean sir?

Comment: That symbol inside a `foreach` statement allows us to use both the key and value in the loop.

Comment: it giving same value sir, i dunno it doesn't work i think

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($_POST['answer'], $_POST['key'])` ?

Comment: here sir , array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(1) "4" } array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" }

Answer (score 0):

sample 1:

```php
<?php

$x=0;
foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $answer) {
    if(in_array($answer, $_POST['key'])){
        $x++;
    }
}
echo $x;
?>
```

sample 2:

```php
<?php
$res = array_intersect($_POST['answer'], $_POST['key']);
echo count($res);
?>
```

Comment: oh no sir its not working, it because when answer number 1 same as key number 2, it still return 1 or true .

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(1) "4" } array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" } . when im using your method number 1, when im posting the answer on array()[0]=3 and they key on the other array array()[1]=3 it still return correct answer or +1. i dont want that.

Comment: You want to get rid of duplicates in arrray1？

Comment: no i mean it need to be same index when 1st-array[0] same value with 2nd-array[0] then it $x++. when im using your method it still $x++ even 1st-array[0] same value with 2nd-array[1] . it still giving $x++ when the number not in the same index.